How to inverse transform 4(1 + x2)−1/π, 0<x<1 for importance sampling
Example 5.10 Statistical Computing with R (Rizzo) 
Estimate the following using importance sampling 
$$\int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}$$
u <- runif(m) #f4, inverse transform method
x <- tan(pi * u / 4)
fg <- g(x) / (4 / ((1 + x^2) * pi))
theta.hat <- mean(fg)
se <- sd(fg)

\begin{align}f_4(x)&=\frac{4(1+x^2)^{-1}}{\pi},&& 0<x<1\\
u&=\frac{4(1+x^2)^{-1}}{\pi}\\
u\pi&=\frac{4}{(1+x^2)}\\
u\pi(1+x^2)&=4\\
1+x^2&=\frac{4}{u\pi}\end{align}
Where did the 1 go? How does tan convert $x^2=\frac{4}{u\pi}$ to $x=tan\left(\frac{u\pi}{4}\right)$

$\int_0^x\frac{4(1+t^2)^{-1}}{\pi}dt$
$\frac{4}{\pi}\int_0^x\frac{1}{1+t^2}dt$
$\frac{4}{\pi}tan^{-1}(x)=u$
$tan^{-1}(x)=\frac{u\pi}{4}$
$x=tan\left(\frac{u\pi}{4}\right)$
